# When I am going to build android project in Android Studio, it shows build success in gradle console. But it reports error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, java-8, android-gradle-plugin

When I am going to build android project in Android Studio, it shows build success in gradle console. But it reports following problem.

> Error:Auto make failure: Abnormal build process termination: 
>   /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java -Xmx1000m -Djava.awt.headless=true
>   -Djava.endorsed.dirs=\"\" -Djdt.compiler.useSingleThread=true -Dcompile.parallel=true -Drebuild.on.dependency.change=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dio.netty.initialSeedUniquifier=-47766016155846999 --offline -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djps.file.types.component.name=FileTypeManager -Duser.language=en -Duser.country=IN -Didea.paths.selector=AndroidStudio2.3 -Didea.home.path=/opt/android-studio -Didea.config.path=/home/lt-41/.AndroidStudio2.3/config -Didea.plugins.path=/home/lt-41/.AndroidStudio2.3/config/plugins -Djps.log.dir=/home/lt-41/.AndroidStudio2.3/system/log/build-log -Djps.fallback.jdk.home=/opt/android-studio/jre/jre -Djps.fallback.jdk.version=1.8.0_112-release -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/lt-41/.AndroidStudio2.3/system/compile-server/*temp*
>   -Dcom.android.studio.gradle.offline.mode=false -Dcom.android.studio.gradle.configuration.on.demand=true -Dcom.android.studio.gradle.home.path=/home/lt-41/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-3.3-all/55gk2rcmfc6p2dg9u9ohc3hw9/gradle-3.3
>   -Dcom.android.studio.gradle.java.home.path=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle -Dcom.android.studio.gradle.project.path=/home/lt-41/AndroidStudioProjects/AndroidApp/EmployeeManagementSystem -Dcom.android.studio.gradle.use.verbose.logging=false -Dcom.android.studio.gradle.build.mode=COMPILE_JAVA -Dcom.android.studio.gradle.gradle.tasks.0=assemble -classpath /opt/android-studio/lib/jps-launcher.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/lib/tools.jar:/opt/android-studio/lib/optimizedFileManager.jar:/opt/android-studio/lib/ecj-4.5.2.jar
>   org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.Launcher
>   /opt/android-studio/lib/snappy-in-java-0.5.1.jar:/opt/android-studio/lib/rt/jps-plugin-system.jar:/opt/android-studio/lib/annotations.jar:/opt/android-studio/lib/jna.jar:/opt/android-studio/lib/netty-all-4.1.2.Final.jar:/opt/android-studio/lib/javac2.jar:/opt/android-studio/lib/jps-builders.jar:/opt/android-studio/lib/nanoxml-2.2.3.jar:/opt/android-studio/lib/jdom.jar:/opt/android-studio/lib/openapi.jar:/opt/android-studio/lib/resources_en.jar:/opt/android-studio/lib/oromatcher.jar:/opt/android-studio/lib/idea_rt.jar:/opt/android-studio/lib/asm-all.jar:/opt/android-studio/lib/trove4j.jar:/opt/android-studio/lib/protobuf-2.5.0.jar:/opt/android-studio/lib/jps-model.jar:/opt/android-studio/lib/log4j.jar:/opt/android-studio/lib/jna-platform.jar:/opt/android-studio/lib/jgoodies-forms.jar:/opt/android-studio/lib/util.jar:/opt/android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-windows-amd64-0.11.jar:/opt/android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/opt/android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-model-groovy-3.2.jar:/opt/android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-process-services-3.2.jar:/opt/android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-base-services-3.2.jar:/opt/android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-freebsd-amd64-0.11.jar:/opt/android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-tooling-api-3.2.jar:/opt/android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-model-core-3.2.jar:/opt/android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/objenesis-1.2.jar:/opt/android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/minlog-1.2.jar:/opt/android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/reflectasm-1.07.jar:/opt/android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-base-services-groovy-3.2.jar:/opt/android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-cli-3.2.jar:/opt/android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/commons-io-2.2.jar:/opt/android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/jna-3.2.7.jar:/opt/android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-osx-i386-0.11.jar:/opt/android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-native-3.2.jar:/opt/android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-linux-i386-0.11.jar:/opt/android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-wrapper-3.1.jar:/opt/android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-dependency-management-3.2.jar:/opt/android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-logging-3.2.jar:/opt/android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/resources_en.jar:/opt/android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-osx-amd64-0.11.jar:/opt/android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-0.11.jar:/opt/android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-resources-3.2.jar:/opt/android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-tooling-extension-impl.jar:/opt/android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-messaging-3.2.jar:/opt/android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-linux-amd64-0.11.jar:/opt/android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-tooling-extension-api.jar:/opt/android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/kryo-2.22.jar:/opt/android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle.jar:/opt/android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-core-3.2.jar:/opt/android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-wrapper-3.2.jar:/opt/android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-freebsd-i386-0.11.jar:/opt/android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/guava-jdk5-17.0.jar:/opt/android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-windows-i386-0.11.jar:/opt/android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-jps-plugin.jar:/opt/android-studio/lib/ant/lib/ant.jar:/opt/android-studio/lib/groovy-all-2.4.6.jar:/opt/android-studio/lib/gson-2.5.jar:/opt/android-studio/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.10.jar:/opt/android-studio/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar:/opt/android-studio/lib/gson-2.5.jar:/opt/android-studio/plugins/android/lib/jarutils.jar:/opt/android-studio/lib/gson-2.5.jar:/opt/android-studio/plugins/android/lib/jarutils.jar:/opt/android-studio/plugins/IntelliLang/lib/intellilang-jps-plugin.jar:/opt/android-studio/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-jps-plugin.jar:/opt/android-studio/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-rt-constants.jar:/opt/android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-jps-plugin.jar:/opt/android-studio/plugins/android/lib/jps/android-jps-plugin.jar:/opt/android-studio/plugins/android/lib/jps/android-gradle-jps.jar:/opt/android-studio/plugins/android/lib/android-common.jar:/opt/android-studio/plugins/android/lib/android-rt.jar:/opt/android-studio/plugins/android/lib/sdk-common.jar:/opt/android-studio/plugins/android/lib/repository.jar:/opt/android-studio/plugins/android/lib/sdklib.jar:/opt/android-studio/lib/android-base-common.jar:/opt/android-studio/plugins/android/lib/jarutils.jar:/opt/android-studio/plugins/android/lib/layoutlib-api.jar:/opt/android-studio/plugins/android/lib/manifest-merger.jar
>   org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain 127.0.0.1 38691
>   e67c1c0f-6ec8-4840-ad9b-a6cc179fe0d6
>   /home/lt-41/.AndroidStudio2.3/system/compile-server Unrecognized
>   option: --offline Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
>   Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Comment: do you have the JDK installed in your computer?

Comment: Yes! I have JDK 8.

Answer (score 0):

one of the following will work for you,

Change below file to modify vm heap option.

```
C:\Program Files\Android\android-studio\bin\studio.exe.vmoptions
```

**increase -Xms1024m to -Xms2048m and restart Android Studio.**

OR

1. Open the Control Panel
2. Go to System
3. Go to Advanced Systems Properties
4. Then Environment Variables
5. In System Variables, click Add
6. New Variable Name: _JAVA_OPTIONS
7. New Variable Value: -Xmx2048M
8. Click OK

Comment: I am using Ubuntu OS.